# Why does the indentation disappear when I copy VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel, indentation, listings

- Windows 7 64 bit
- Office 2010

I need to copy Visual  Basic out of MS's editor into a `.tex`-document and intend to use it with the [listings](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

Whether I paste the code into TeXStudio or Notepad++, all the indentation is gone. Pasting into Windows' own vanilla editor, all line breaks are gone as well, so it's basically all mushy. :/

What I've tried so far with S&E (partly with Regex enabled on a case-dependent basis)

- S&E for `\t` ->  (4 spaces) via Regex, does not work as there are no tabs in the code.
- S&E with 4 spaces -> 4 spaces does not lead to any change whatsoever (it was worht a try).
- S&E for `\n` -> `\r`: no change.

How can I keep the indentation out of the VBA editor? This is getting so annoying. :(

### Solution

Layer 8 error due to the day-to-day routine: TeXStudio has "automatic indentation" enabled by default and as VBA code is not recognized, no indentation for the pasted code. Had to temporarily disable this option.

Comment: no repro for me - select all code ctrl+c in VBE and ctrl+v in notepad++ and i get indentation

Comment: @mehow Ok, that is correct. This is probably about Notepad++ -> TeXStudio then... hm. :/

Comment: @mehow Your comment helped, thanks. Solution in op.

Comment: Please put answers in Answer section, not in OP. (even if it's your own answer)

Answer (score 2):

As TeXStudio has "automatic indentation" enabled by default and the VBA code pasted into TeXStudio was not recognized and thus no automatic indentation was done. So for this code (or: plain text) to be indented proberly, I had to temporarily disable this option under 'Editor' in the options.